# How to add a new file to an existing repository using VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I had a single python script, but I separated the code into different files eg. Grace.py, Grace1.py etc.

I want to add these new files to my git repository that I already created but I don't know how. How do I get all three code scripts to be in one repository?

Comment: `git add Grace.py Grace1.py`?

Comment: It may be helpful to post the directory structure of the files you are talking about.

Comment: the output of `git status` would be helpfull to answer this.
Also Consider reading learning more about git [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes)

Answer (score 2):

I would really recommend using the CLI of git instead of vscode, at least at the begining, but if you insist on using vscode for that, this easily done with this explanation:

1. press on the version control button(#1 in the picture)
2. hover the files you want to add and press the '+' button (#2)
3. When you are done adding, commit your work pressing on the 'v'(#3) and then add a message on the text box(#4) and press enter.

[image]

This will create a new commit to save changes **locally.**

To save the code in a remote repository you need to push your commits. You can do it using the the push command. Again, I will recommend using CLI but if you insist you can use vscode for that like this(press the 3 dots (...) button to enter to the below menu):

[image]

**P.s. Make sure your repository saves the proper remote destination.**

Comment: Good day, thank you. I am not too familiar with vscode, although I do get what you outlined there but in order to make use of vscode and git, I have to link my repository to vscode but I'm not certain that it has been done. I say this because in the example you gave above, there is a .py file but mine is only showing readme.md. How do i go about this?

Comment: @Chudyn can you please append the output for `git status`? In the directory of the project.

Comment: Also might be helpful to know output for `git remote -v`

Comment: on Vscode? it says  On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'. Don't know if this is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution. After much reading online and also guidance from Sedki Sghari.

Just by the left of the picture below, this is where my branch is. I needed to switch from the main branch to the one I intended to make changes. As I clicked on it, it asked to select a ref to checkout. The branch I intend to be on was Newbranch and so I inputed it and checked out of the main.

[image: I checked out from the main brain]
[image: searched for Newbranch]

Once changes were made, I committed and pushed. Using  git commit -m and git push respectively.

Comment: I wrote an article about the basics of git. here is the link if you wanna take a look https://sedki.medium.com/understanding-git-76b7a36e1525

Answer (score 0):

would you please explain in which folder your new scripts are relative to your main directory. If all files are in the same directory (folder) then you can just commit you new changes and push it to your repo. to check from your terminal, open Vscode, drag and drop you folder and let vscode open it, press **ctrl** and **`** to open your terminal(or go to **view** and then **terminal** )and run:

```
git status
```

If you are able to see your changes:

```
git add .
git commit -m'add my other files'
git push
```

If you have no changes, that means that your scripts are in a different folder, just move them to the same folder and do the steps above.

I hope this helps. Please share with us if you still face some issues.

Comment: Hi there! Please note that OP asked how to do it with vscode

Comment: I had three tasks to perform but all codes were placed in a single code snippet. I have made corrections as guided and will like to commit all the changes made with respect to the code. I do not want all 3 tasks to be in a single file, so I made my corrections in separate files eg. grace.py etc. I will like to commit these changes to the repository and request for review by the contributor.  I do not know if I should just upload these files or commit via vscode. irrespective, I will like to know the best way to do this as well as learn how to make use of Vscode.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmYgr.png here is an image of the correction I was requested to make.

Comment: The best way to do it, is by pushing your changes via vscode, as shown above, get used to the terminal as it makes your life easier in the long run. when you push your changes, it will be visible to all contributors if you are the owner of the main repo, and similarly, if someone else pushes some changes you will be able to see it when you do a " git status ", if there are some new changes you can run : "git pull " to have the new updated code.

Comment: okay. Please can you put me through step by step if you do not mind. I will really appreciate it. I am still new to Vscode.

Comment: Yes sure, but first i need to know from where to start, can you please confirm if : you have git installed and i assume you are using windows. to see if you have git you can open vscode and on the upper-left corner you will see terminal, click "new terminal" and then enter this command "git --version" and then enter. if you see something like 'git version 2.29' that means you have it, if not your shell will tell you that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Git is a version control system that allows you to track different versions of your code, in other words it keeps a history of all  previous commits so it is easier to roll back to a previous stable version if the current one is faulty.

Comment: Thank you. I have git installed.

Comment: I have gotten to a part where I have to clone my repository but the file in question is not in the folder for me to make changes. The file is grace.py but it is not there.

Comment: ok, great, now run "git status". you will be able to see your changes if you have any; something like : "modified:   Grace.py", If you don't have any changes you will get "our branch is up to date with 'origin/main ...nothing to commit' which means that your local branch(code in your computer) is up to date with the remote repo in github. If your git is not linked to the remote repo in github you will something like: "fatal: not a git repository", that means you need to let git know about your repo in github, which is very simple to do. so run git status and let me know what you get exactly.

Comment: git version 2.30.0.windows.1, this is for git --version
for the git status, it says:
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   WORKING WITH THE DRESSLER. I initially copied all the codes in the 3 files and was just trying to understand the environment probably why it says modified.

Comment: I have a theory though. I maybe wrong but there was a pull request done of which i merge my main and a new branch together. I am wondering, countless times i have cloned but this specific .py file that I want to make changes to is never found in the folder. is it because i merged the main and the new folder?

Comment: it's possible that you merged in a different branch, to check your branches run "git branch" the one with * is the one you are currently in, to change to the other one (if you see only one that means you only have that branch), and see if you have your files you can run "git checkout <branch name>" checkout let you switch between branches

Comment: I was able to do it. will post it as answering my question so as not to make the comment section longer than it is supposed to